# How To Retrieve specific node using Xpath c#

Tags: c#, xml, xpath

I have an xml file

```
<BookLib>
  <Book Id="1">
    <Title>Title1</Title>
    <Author>Author1</Author>
    <Publisher>Publisher1</Publisher>
    <Subject />
  </Book>
  <Book Id="2">
    <Title>Title2</Title>
    <Author>Author2</Author>
    <Publisher>Publisher2</Publisher>
    <Subject />
  </Book>
  <Book Id="3">
    <Title>Title3</Title>
    <Author>Author3</Author>
    <Publisher>Author3</Publisher>
    <Subject />
  </Book>
</BookLib>
```

I want to select book id. I tried using this

```
@"/BookLib/Book/Title[contains(translate(text(),'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ','abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz'),'" + searchText + "')]/@Id";
```

in `XPathExpression`

how can i retrieve 'id' using xpath in c#

Comment: Your XML seems malformed for me: Id=1 => `Id="1"`

Comment: Also, you'd said what you tried - but not what the result was. (And do you have to use XPath? I'd personally use LINQ to XML...)

Comment: And your second and third Title havea wrong end tag. <Title/>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since `@Id` is below `Book`, not `Id`, you have to move back up to get it:

```
@"/BookLib/Book/Title[contains(translate(.,'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ', 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz'),'" 
      + searchText.ToLower() + "')]/../@Id";
```

or do the comparison without moving down to `Title` in the first place:

```
@"/BookLib/Book[contains(translate(Title,'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ', 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz'),'" 
      + searchText.ToLower() + "')]/@Id";
```

I personally prefer the latter because it seems a bit cleaner.

Answer (score 0):

First you can use **[fn:lower-case()](http://www.xsltfunctions.com/xsl/fn_lower-case.html) which is better** than [fn:translate](http://www.xsltfunctions.com/xsl/fn_translate.html) as it use Unicode mapping to change the case. So it will work with accent like É->é, À->à, etc.

Then you can **simplify by using [XPath axes](http://www.xmlplease.com/axis)**.

So, to get the @Id, you can use the following XPath (adapt to `C#`) :

```
@"//Book/Title[contains(lower-case(./text()),'" + searchText.ToLower() + "' )]/@Id";
```

Comment: `lower-case()` _would be_ better, if .NET supported XPath 2.0, which it does not.